# Login with status

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a separate table `members` to login. And it has status column. I need to authenticate only members that has status `1`.

For this I have `App/http/Controllers/Members/Auth/LoginController.php` as:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/member-home';

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('member_form');
}

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('member');
}
```

I could override the authenticated method:

```
 protected function authenticated()
    {
      if (Auth::guard('member')->user()->status==0) {
          Auth::guard('member')->logout();
          return view('member_form');
      } 
    }
```

This doesn't allow the login but still doesn't display `These credentials don't match our records`. Still same if I override authenticate method.

Comment: You have a typo in `if (Auth::guard('mwmber')->user()->status==0) {` should by  `if (Auth::guard('member')->user()->status==0) {` ... I think